# How to access Google dev-sources example page?

Tags: google-api

I am reading documentation of the Google Standard Payments (found [here)](https://developers.google.com/standard-payments/guides/cash-fop) and they provided an example of documentation for the encryption using PGP (Here is a PGP library and sample in java that shows handling requests and responses.). When I try to click on the link that gives the sample I am redirected to a web page where I am receiving

`PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission`
on the following [link](https://dev-partners.googlesource.com/standard-payments/ample-cash-java/+/refs/heads/master/amplecash%20server/src/main/java/com/google/standardpayments/sample/amplecash/server/Utils/ImaliPgpUtil.java)

[image]

I am wondering how can I access these documents or read them, I am signed in with a google account but have done nothing with it in terms of signing up for a service, etc. If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be helpful, thank you in advance.

Comment: I sent an email off to google since the page itself doesn't appear to have a feedback link.  I cant tell you how long it will take them to fix it.

Comment: thank you @DaImTo please update if you receive anything back!

Comment: @DaImTo I have a question - which email did you use to contact them? I could not find any email to write to. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry i cant give out email address of others without there permission.  Suffice to say he has access to add this to their internal bug system.  I wouldn't hold your breath on them fixing it anytime soon. I have documentation bug reports that are five years old and still not fixed.

Comment: @DaImTo sure thing, i thought you meant contact to their (googles) support line for api's, not to an employee. thank you for the information regardless!

Comment: I was unable to find a link for bug reporting for that api unfortunately so i had to go directly to the source.

Comment: Its been forwarded to the right people.   I won't hear if its fixed you will just have to check again later.   My Google contact says thank you

Comment: @DaImTo thank you so much for the help - appreciate it !